# Search in my Anki collection, via command line

Tags: open-source, command-line, anki

[Anki](http://ankisrs.net/) is a flashcards app, for instance to memorize obscure vim tricks.

Sometimes I want to quickly search a fact I don't remember, without having to open the Anki GUI.

Is there a script I could use for this?

Requirements:

- Command-line
- No configuration needed, should find the SQLite file itself
- Search all fields, output all fields
- Open source

Comment: Indeed :) that would be nice. But why not ask it as a feature request, builtin in the app?

Comment: I've been looking for something like this forever.

Answer (score 3):

Since anki2 files are sqlite-based, you may try my [filegrep](http://eadmaster.altervista.org/pub/prj/cliapps/filegrep) script.
(It needs [file2txt](http://eadmaster.altervista.org/pub/prj/cliapps/file2txt) and [sqlite3](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/sqlite3) as helpers).

Examples:

```
filegrep ubuntu *.sqlite
filegrep ".*linux" *.anki2
filegrep -r "keyword" path/to/databasedir
```

You can use most of the classic grep switches with it.

The output will be in SQL, which you may filter with other tools.